# I have the following error: "Type error: Too few arguments to function AlbumController::postEdit(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected"

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following problem when trying to edit an "album", hopefully they can help me, I'm a little frustrated haha.

**The Form**

```
<form name="editalbum" action="{{ action('AlbumController@postEdit', $album->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
      <fieldset>
        <h2>Editar <strong>{{$album->name}}</strong></h2>
        <br></br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Nombre del proyecto</label>
          <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $album->name }}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Descripción del proyecto</label>
          <textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="50" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $album->description }}" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="location">Locación:</label>
          <input name="location" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $album->location }}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="year">Año:</label>
          <input name="year" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $album->year }}" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

So far I think everything is going well because I try to post in the ID of the model.

The function:

```
  public function postEdit(Request $request, $id)
{
$album = Album::find($id);
$album = Album::all();
if(count($album) > 0){
$album->name = Input::get('name');
$album->description = Input::get('description');
$album->year = Input::get('year');
$album->location = Input::get('location');
$album->save();
      Alert::success('Successfully Updated', 'Congratulations');
      return view('admin.dashboard');
  } else {
      Alert::error('Facilities not found', 'Error');
      return view('galeries');
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `routes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made error in routes.php
It should look like this:

```
Route::post('albums/update/{id}', ['uses' => 'AlbumController@postEdit']);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution will be to remove the DI Request object

```
public function postEdit($id)
{
//rest of code
}
```

note: the param has to be passed as a array

```
action="{{ action('AlbumController@postEdit', ['id' => $album->id]) }}"
```